# Further Clarification about Previous Question: How do I implement multiple recyclerviews in a viewpager2(+ tablayout) with multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

For further information on the problems that I am facing with my code, please refer to the first question. But I have recognized that the level of detail might be a little too extreme for conveying what I need help with. My essential problem is that I want to implement multiple recyclerviews in a viewpager2 that has a tab layout labeling from Monday to Sunday. At the bottom right hand corner, there is a floating action button that is meant to call an intent to this xml file below. Once the button is clicked for the xml file, it should go back to tablayout and should display the "prescription" as described in the previous question for that specific day.

Main Idea/Problem:  A prescription should be added to the end of the list for a specific day. Basically, I need to have multiple recyclerviews for each of the tabs in the tab layout that can manually have items added onto 1 of 7 recyclerviews.

Best Solution: The best and easiest way for someone to help me is to provide sample code that accomplishes this. Sample code that can function with multiple recyclerviews, a viewpager2, and multiple fragments will help me solve my problem.

Another solution: I have read really good advice here on Stack Overflow related to RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool(), and if someone can explain how I could properly integrate this into my code, that would also be a fine answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".add_medication_to_list">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cf1874"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >
    </android.widget.Toolbar>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/medicine_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop='100dp'
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Enter name of prescription"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/medicine_quantity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="number of medications"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dosage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Enter dosage"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/frequency"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="How often do you take your prescription?"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:hint="Time to take medicine"
         />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:text="Add new prescription"
         />
</RelativeLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. Fixed it with finish().